# Retornar valor al subscribirse con Angular 9

Tags: angular

os explico un poco la funcionalidad que necesito.
Tengo una funcion para recuperar imagenes de minio y convertirlas a URL. Una vez tengo la URL tengo que añadirlo a un array para luego recorrerlo y mostrar esas imagenes.
El problema viene cuando intento recorrerlo, que siempre me dice que es indefinido...
Os paso ejemplos de codigo:

Esta es la funcion que recibe el objeto para transformarlo en url:

```
showImg(file) {
    this.s3Service
      .s3getfile(file, (progress: any) => {
        this.progress = (progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total;
      })
      .subscribe(
        (s3GetObjectOutput) => {
          const blobParts: any = s3GetObjectOutput.Body;
          this.buildImage(blobParts, file.mime, pdf);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        },
      );
  }
  buildImage(blobparts: any, mime: string) {
    const str = Buffer.from(blobparts).toString('base64');
    this.croquisPDF.push(`data:${mime};base64,${str}`);
  }
```

Y en la funcion donde genero el PDF:

```
    this.referencePieces$.getValue().forEach((element: any) => {
       this.showImg(element.croquisFile)
    })
     this.croquisPDF.forEach(croquis=> {
       doc.addImage(croquis, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 100, 100)
})
```

Cuando recorro croquisPDF para mostrar las imagenes me dice que es indefinido... Y no lo entiendo...

¿Alguna ayuda?

Mil gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando trabajas con observables tu código *deja de ser secuencial (1)* y tienes que empezar a trabajar *en base a reacciones (2)*.

(1) Orden probable en el que ocurren las cosas

Corre forEach que ejecuta los showImg

Corre forEach que recorre croquisPDF

Termina forEach que recorre croquisPDF porque no hay nada

Termina forEach que ejecuta los showImg (después de que ejecutaste el recorrido de croquis)

(2) Lo que se debe hacer es esperar a que terminen todos los showImg, esto tiene que ver con await Observables y programación un poco más avanzada de estos. Solución sugerida:

```
// showImg ahora retorna un Observable el cual tiene un pipe lo que hace
// es que al terminar s3getfile se hace un paso extra el cual es ejecutar 
// buildImage
showImg(file): Observable < any > {
    return this.s3Service
        .s3getfile(file, (progress: any) => {
            this.progress = (progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total;
        }).pipe(
            map(
                (s3GetObjectOutput) => {
                    const blobParts: any = s3GetObjectOutput.Body;
                    this.buildImage(blobParts, file.mime, pdf);
                }
            ),
            catchError(
                error => console.error(error)
            )
        );
}

buildImage(blobparts: any, mime: string) {
    const str = Buffer.from(blobparts).toString('base64');
    this.croquisPDF.push(`data:${mime};base64,${str}`);
}

// ahora showImg retorna observables entonces lo que haces es generar un
// arreglo de observables 
const arrayObservables = this.referencePieces$.getValue().map((element: any) => this.showImg(element.croquisFile))

// forkJoin lo que hace es ejecutar un arreglo de observables y cuando todos
// terminan emite la respuestas de todos en un arreglo
// cuando te suscribes al forkJoin es cuando se ejecutan todos los showImg
forkJoin(arrayObservables).subscribe(
    respuestas => {
        // y esta es la parte de la reacción, una vez terminadas todas 
        // las ejecuciones de showImg es que se itera sobre croquisPDF
        this.croquisPDF.forEach(croquis => {
            doc.addImage(croquis, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 100, 100)
        })
    }
)
```